# Contact form mail handler example for go on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

To my surprise I did not find a contact form mail handler example for go? I don't feel like making a wheel today, are there examples available?

EDIT: (cut and paste answer)

```
package bin

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    netMail "net/mail"
    "appengine"
    "appengine/mail"
)

func contact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    name := r.FormValue("name")
    email := r.FormValue("email")
    subject := r.FormValue("subject")
    message := r.FormValue("message")
    msg := &mail.Message{
            Sender:  name + " <...@yourappid.appspotmail.com>",
            To:      []string{"...@..."},
            ReplyTo: email,
            Subject: subject,
            Body:    message,
            Headers: netMail.Header{
                "On-Behalf-Of": []string{email},
            },
    }
    if err := mail.Send(c, msg); err != nil {
        c.Errorf("Couldn't send email: %v", err)
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Mail NOT send! Error")
    }else{
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Mail send.")
    }
}
```

NOTE:

1) `ReplyTo` only works in gmail if `Sender` and `To` are different.

2) `Sender` should have admin role in google cloud console or `something@yourappid.appspotmail.com`.

Comment: Perhaps https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/ will help.

Comment: Possibly: Unpack into struct using http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema + validate fields (package unicode/utf8) for sanity, mail as per above link and log success/failure for follow-up. You could also use the gochimp library + Mandrill API if you so choose.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/#Go_Sending_mail has more info on how to authenticate in app engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely failing because the `Sender` can only be

- an email of a developer of you app, or
- `something@yourappid.appspotmail.com`

I suggest that you hard-code the sender's email, and use the `On-Behalf-Of` header in which you include the original sender's name/email.

Also, `WriteString` accepts a single `string`, not a `[]string` slice.

The minimum modifications for your example would be:

```
…
msg := &mail.Message{
        Sender:  name + " <developer@yourapp.com>",
        To:      []string{"...@gmail.com"},
        Subject: subject,
        Body:    message,
        Headers: netMail.Header{
            "On-Behalf-Of": []string{email},
        },
}
…
```

Also, you'll need to make sure the user's name doesn't actually contain an email address. That could cause you problems…

The best would be to do as @elithrar suggested and validate your form.

Comment: Thanks two things that do not compile yet `[]string{subject}` and `[]string{message}` `cannot use []string literal (type []string) as type string in field value`, my go knowledge is very limited at the moment. see edit

Comment: `subject`, `body` and `on-behalf-of` should just be `string`, not `[]string`. See http://play.golang.org/p/_-Va7qC-hZ

Comment: @Intermernet not correct. `On-Behalf-Of` should be `[]string`. The other two should be `string`, let me fix my example.